# Sending file through django form using ajax and djangorestframework 403 error

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to send pdf file from django template form using ajax and get data in views.py using djangorestframwork. Works with usual data, but in this case I get 403 error

forms.py

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('upload',)
        widgets = {
            'upload': forms.FileInput(
                attrs={'id': 'fileinput', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Say something...'}
            ),
        }
```

template and jQuery/js:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="pdf_form">
{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}


      <input type="submit" class="">Save</input>
  </form>




 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {

function upload() {
   alert($('#fileinput').val())

   $.ajax({
        url: '/upload_ticket/',
        type : "POST", // http method
        dataType: 'json',
        data : { 'file' : $('#fileinput').val() }, // data sent with the post request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function() {
          alert('succes');
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function() {
           alert('error');
        }
    });
};






    $('.pdf_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('it works!');
    console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
    upload();
});



});

</script>
```

urls.py:

```
    url(r'^upload_ticket/$', views.upload_ticket),
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def upload_ticket(request):
    return Response(request.data)
```

I'v been debugging for hours, but can't find error. What is wrong with my implementation?

```
POST /upload_ticket/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58
```

Comment: I believe you might need to pass `csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"` in your ajax data dictionary.

Comment: @jape true. I didn't know djangp provides protection against csrf when sending data in this way

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it at least! Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the csrf token in your API call, so thats the culprit.
This should work for you.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/upload_ticket/',
    type : "POST", // http method
    dataType: 'json',
    data : { 'file' : $('#fileinput').val(), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value }, // data sent with the post request

    // handle a successful response
    success : function() {
      alert('succes');
    },

    // handle a non-successful response
    error : function() {
       alert('error');
    }
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) 
             {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');


function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Add after jQuery library including, it always pass csrftoken to your request, you don't need manually pass csrftoken anymore !

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

Answer (score -1):

403 Error occurs because you are no sending the csrf token in your request,

You have to set the csrf token to your request header, you can use this [code](https://github.com/realpython/django-form-fun/blob/master/part1/main.js) and at the end of your js file or your js block, and all should be ok.

Also i would like to recommend you this [post](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) about django/and ajax, was very useful for my at the beginning

Comment: sending csrf token and still error